# are there separate buffer for read and write library calls?

Tags: c, sockets, operating-system

i am trying to understand how data is read and write from same file descriptor.

```
network - socket
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)
    write(sockfd, buff, large_buffer_size)
```

while the program/os was writing data to file descriptor, let's say simultaneously we were receiving data from server.

now, i want to know how it is ensured data is not corrupted i.e data that was to be written and data that was to be read are not mixed as we are pointing to same file descriptor?

Comment: Yes, there are.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli can you share some links / videos where i can learn how this being handled.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal: the details of this are entirely as the discretion of the operating system developers. The way Linux implements it has been described at http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html – however, this article is a couple of years old, and the information therein may no longer accurately reflect how things are now. In case of doubt, read the source code.

Comment: The socket has a send buffer and a receive buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets are unusual in that they provide full-duplex communication via a single file descriptor.  The kernel does what is needed to make that work smoothly and correctly, which includes, yes, buffering outgoing and incoming data separately.  Semantically, each socket very much does bind together two separate channels, one for each direction.  You can even shut those channels down independently of each other.